# sql connecttion error in the registeration page

Tags: php

I used the help page http://youhack.me/2010/04/01/building-a-registration-system-with-email-verification-in-php/ 
Changed the database name to

- DataBase name: 819903
- DataBase username: 819903
- DataBase password: equal with account password
- DataBase host: localhost

But receive the following error after filling the registration form that hosted at myproject.6te.net  and receive the error

```
Database Error Occured Query Failed .
```

You can test it at http://myproject.6te.net/ and give suggestions that why the error is coming inspite of making all the changes in the necessary files.
Is it hosting server error or database connection type error although I have made all the changes as per the requirement?

Answer (score 1):

It's this part:

```
// Make sure the email address is available:
35          $query_verify_email = "SELECT * FROM members  WHERE Email ='$Email'";
36          $result_verify_email = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_verify_email);
37          if (!$result_verify_email) { //if the Query Failed ,similar to if($result_verify_email==false)
38              echo ' Database Error Occured ';
39          }
40   
41          if (mysqli_num_rows($result_verify_email) == 0) { // IF no previous user is using this email .
42   
43              // Create a unique  activation code:
44              $activation = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
45   
46              $query_insert_user =
47                  "INSERT INTO `members` ( `Username`, `Email`, `Password`, `Activation`) VALUES ( '$name', '$Email', '$Password', '$activation')";
48   
49              $result_insert_user = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_insert_user);
50              if (!$result_insert_user) {
51                  echo 'Query Failed ';
- See more at: http://youhack.me/2010/04/01/building-a-registration-system-with-email-verification-in-php/#sthash.V54kddyz.dpuf
```

Change this:

```
if (!$result_verify_email) { //if the Query Failed ,similar to if($result_verify_email==false)
    echo ' Database Error Occured ';
}
```

into:

```
    if (!$result_verify_email) { //if the Query Failed ,similar to if($result_verify_email==false)
        echo ' Database Error Occured ';
echo mysqli_error($dbc);
    }
```

And tell me what it says. Athough it will probably say "no connection to database" Which means that your database username, password or database is not correct.

Comment: My dear,
Please check now the page register the account but unable to verify it.
also tell that where you taking the files
$query_verify_email = "SELECT * FROM members  WHERE Email ='$Email'";
36          $result_verify_email = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_verify_email);
37          if (!$result_verify_email) { //if the Query Failed ,similar to if($result_verify_email==false)
38              echo ' Database Error Occured ';
are you making modifications or also you are using below .
I understand below there are certainly you are suggesting a modification in the later discussion?
Yes?
Are you?

Comment: my dear ,changes are made in the database file that is my database user and name also?